# Is there a framework/app for testing distributed systems or just network apps?

Tags: testing, network-programming, boost-asio, p2p

I want to simulate at least 9 clients to test my p2p engine. And i want to make some of them to be behind NAT and some of them to have all ports unlocked. Also, i would like to see log which creates each of them. I am not capable of running 9VM simultaneously, so I'm here to ask experts: is there something i can use for testing it?

I am using Boost library in my app.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's the perfect solution for linux users: http://www.nrl.navy.mil/itd/ncs/products/core

I will keep this answer updated if im wrong.

UPDATE: It works like a charm. Firewall rules can be set for each node. It is not using that much of memory too, so it is possible to make even large network topologies. There is a possibility to run a terminal-per-node. So you can test many different scenarios to test out your application. Good luck.